# DecimalFormat("¤#,##0") prefixing Â in unit tests

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting, decimalformat

I'm writing unit tests for a method that formats some numbers and when I use `DecimalFormat("¤#,##0")` it always prefixes `Â` in the unit tests. It does not display the `Â` in the XML output file that the numbers are written to, but it does in the unit tests. For example:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("¤#,##0");
String str = decimalFormat.format(5000);
```

The XML output file will hold the value `$5,000`, but when I debug or unit test `str = "Â$5,000"`

Is this expected behavior or is something wrong? The `DecimalFormat` documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) says that,

> Currency sign, replaced by currency symbol. If doubled, replaced by international currency symbol. If present in a pattern, the monetary decimal separator is used instead of the decimal separator.

I understand that it is probably getting the currency symbol from the default locale, but why does the `Â` show up?

If it is expected behavior great, I'll just use the replace method, but if it is not expected I want to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Where does it display wrong ? This could well be a terminal encoding issue.

Comment: Could it be something like a interpreted BOM or any other non printable character?

Comment: On the very next line of code after `String str = decimalFormat.format(5000);` the string is getting added as a value to a particular element in an xml object. When I assert the value of that element I get the Â$5,000, but like I said, when view the fully built XML the value is $5,000.